# Get Unicorn to only access vendor/cache gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, unicorn

It seems when I run `bundle package` then `bundle install --local` then I run `unicorn_rails`, unicorn is still accessing system gems. I keep getting :

> You have already activated rack 1.5.2, but your Gemfile requires rack
>   1.2.8. Using bundle exec may solve this.

And it shouldn't because rack 1.2.8 is in the vendor/cache.

`bundle exec` wont work because it seems to be a resource hog and the whole point of `bundle package` is avoid this whole mess in  the first place.

So how do I get unicorn to get bundle environment to only use the vendor/cache gems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bundle install --local` takes gems in `vendor/local` and installs them using whatever your default `gem` command does.  By default, that is a system-wide install.  If you're using RVM or something else, it'll be in your current RVM gemset.

If you're installing in production, and you want to limit the app to your gems from `vendor/local`, you want to do `bundle install --deployment`.  This will install the gems into `vendor/bundle` and set Bundler up to use those gems (and only those gems, not the system ones).  If the gems aren't in `vendor/local`, it will download them.  It won't update your `Gemfile.lock`, and best practice is to keep all your gems in `vendor/cache` up to date to prevent it from even trying to download gems.

You don't need to use `bundle exec` unless you're running a binary from one of the gems.  If you're running `rails server` and having this problem, the reason is that the `rails` command is running from the shell's `$PATH`.  It's presumably a different version of Rails than the one you'd like to use.

If that's the case, your options are to track down the path to the version of `rails` you want and run it explicitly, to use `bundle exec`, or to run `bundle install --binstubs --deployment` and add *that* `bin` directory to your `PATH`.  I haven't noticed any overhead from `bundle exec`, but if you're concerned about that and still want to scope everything to your bundle, then use `--binstubs` (this is how Heroku does it, by the way).

Comment: Followup note: `rails` is no longer a problem in this scenario, because it now just runs `script/rails` if that's present, which will be Bundle-scoped.  Everything else about binary paths still applies to other gems (`rspec` being a notable one).  If you're running `unicorn` or `foreman` or `guard` or `spork` or any other Ruby gem binary, you'll need to address the path concern.

Comment: THANKS @Jimmy Stewart! Im really wanting to keep all my gems in my repository. I have another rails app running (Redmine) and it seems conflicts are always happening. Also, I dont want to rely on rubygems.org always being there or always being available, and in some cases github gems. Is bundle install --binstubs --deployment or bundle install --deployment the best way to make a "self contained" app? If so what is the purposed then of the cache directory if the gems are now in vendor/bundle?

Comment: `bundle install --binstubs --local --deployment` is what you want.  Creates binstubs in your project, prevents downloading gems, installs gems into `vendor/bundle`, and only uses those gems.  The `vendor/cache` directory holds the Gem _source code_ (`.gem` files).  The `vendor/bundle` directory is filled with the unpacked, compiled (if necessary), ready-to-use gems.  It's where `require` will end up loading them from when your app runs.